# SSH port 22: Resource temporarily unavailable

Tags: ssh, port

I can't connect anymore to a server which has functioning fine up to know. I am using ssh. The error message is:

> ssh: connect to host port 22: Resource temporarily unavailable

The problem seems to be related to my machine as I could SSH to the server from another machine. I am using WSL under Windows 10, but also tried Powershell, WinSCP, Putty and tried to connect with the firewall deactivated. I laso tried restarting ssh.

`sudo /etc/init.d/ssh restart`

This happens after multiple ssh attempts through gnu parallel.

Comment: Try to check if any firewalls block the connection. Also check if the key is valid and working.

Comment: I already tried with the firewall deactivated. How do I check for key validity?